# Excel: remove everything except one character after 3rd space

Tags: excel, function, find

This formula removes everything after the 3rd space in a cell, I want to leave one character after the 3rd space. I'm not sure how to make the adjustment. Thanks for your help.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1, FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)+1)+1),"")
```

[image: Formula]

Or

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),3))+1)
```

Or, according to, Allen Wyatt [here](https://excel.tips.net/T003324_Finding_the_Nth_Occurrence_of_a_Character.html), using a function I have never heard of before called SEARCHB,

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCHB(" ",A1,(SEARCHB(" ",A1,(SEARCHB(" ",A1,1)+1))+1))+1)
```

Which a quick [read](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) tells me I might as well do the more familiar

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,(SEARCH(" ",A1,(SEARCH(" ",A1,1)+1))+1))+1)
```

> SEARCHB counts 2 bytes per character only when a DBCS language is set
>   as the default language. Otherwise SEARCHB behaves the same as SEARCH,
>   counting 1 byte per character.

---

### Note:

If you actually meant you only wanted the first character after the third space, and nothing else, then use the fact you have found the position of the 3rd space and added one, with `FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)+1)+1`, to combine with `MID` function to return one character starting at that position i.e.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)+1)+1,1)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

You can use that same logic with the other solutions I listed at the top.